# iptables like forwarding of packets with pfctl on mac os

Tags: firewall, pfctl

I would like to build a bridge between two interfaces with pf, like with iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

This snippet just forwards all packets from wifi to an ethernet interface. How to accomplish same with pf? I see very often something like this in pf.conf:

```
rdr on en0 inet proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.186 port 1234 -> 192.168.1.198 port 80
nat on en0 inet proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.198 port 80 -> 192.168.1.186
```

But isn't it just a forward for a specific port and not a range of ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest obtaining the Murus App which is a GUI for pf. It is difficult to find documentation. BSD Unix is where pf came from but Apple seems to have a different flavor of it. Not everything in the BSD docs work on Macs.

Murus Firewall makes it far easier to configure pf. There are NAT settings that seem to do what you want.

https://www.murusfirewall.com/murus/

Comment: murus is an paid app, the free version is very limited in its features. but thanks anyway. It seems like pf is something very far from iptables. Simple tasks done very complex.

Comment: Seek out BSD documentation as pf comes from FreeBSD, OpenBSD.  Just keep in mind, it's not exactly the same but darn close.  I used Murus to build firewall rules for corporate use. You can distribute the pf configurations without Murus.  So I just packaged the pf config and pushed to many Macs.  Using Murus to update the rules and test.